# Adding Support Play Music In my google-assistant project

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, google-smart-home

Right now I am building a project smart home with google-voice-assistant API. I have registered the Device Model in my project in console.actions.google and have implemented it in my device program and working fine. But when I tried requesting "Play Music", Google API answered, "Sorry, I can't do it on this device". What must I do for google-voice-assistant API can run the request ?

Comment: If you are doing a smart home project, can you provide more details about the device type and the associated attributes ? Also, can you share details as to where you implemented the google voice assistant api ?

Answer (score 0):

The google smart home ecosystem provides capabilities to support speaker device type. The list of required and recommended traits associated with this device type along with there SYNC, EXECUTE AND REQUEST payload can we found [here](https://developers.home.google.com/cloud-to-cloud/guides/speaker). For the issue being faced by you, MediaState and TransportControl are the traits which might help you in rectifying your issue and giving you the desired results.